# "swollen" vs. "swelling"

Tags: meaning

I am aware that "swelling" is a type of symptom, the basic form of which is "swell". Consider these

> I have a swelling in my right knee.
>
> My right knee is swollen.

Do they mean the same thing?

Cambridge Dictionary gives this example for "swollen"

> swollen glands

and this for "swelling"

> Put your foot into cold water to help the swelling go down

without saying when to use which, could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Swollen" is an adjective, and in your examples, "swelling" is a noun. 
 That should govern the uses of the words.

As to your first two example sentences, there may be a difference between "swelling in my knee" and "my knee is swollen", because the first could refer to something within the knee, and the second could refer to the whole knee.

Answer (score 0):

'Swell' is a verb. 'Swelling' is a symptom.

**Swollen** only functions as an adjective.

> My right knee is swollen.

**Swelling** can function as a noun referring to the symptomatic/injured area.

> The swelling on my right knee is larger today than it was yesterday.

That said, the second example sounds like it's not the whole knee that's swollen, but a particular bump or lump on it that is swollen.

You could used bruised/bruising in a similar way

> My right knee is bruised.
>
> The bruising on my right knee is larger today.